# Why isn't a handler on the same element run after stopPropagation

Tags: jquery, events, stoppropagation

With http://jsfiddle.net/mgs_jsfiddle/HXMCs/ why isn't the first event handler run, if the mouse is moved into the sub area?

```
<div class="top">
    <div class="sub"></div>
</div>

$(".top").bind("mouseover mouseout", function(e) {
});

$(".top").on("mouseover mouseout", ".sub", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Both handlers are attached to the top element. And the documentation for stopPropagation tells me that "this will not prevent other handlers on the same element from running". So shouldn't the first handler also be called?

Comment: Why are you mixing bind and on?  You can't expect things to work the way they claim when you're not using them the way you're supposed to.  You're listening for events on different elements you just happen to be attaching the listeners at the same place.

Comment: Mixing? Because it makes sense in the real code. There are many subs in a deep hierachy below top. And top must also listen for the events, as top is not covered entirely by the subs.

Comment: Although you delegated event to `.top` it listens to events on `.sub`. jQuery is smart enough to handle delegated events like the normal once.

Comment: I would not think that after reading the documentation. It says "A delegated-events approach attaches an event handler to only one element". Further, if jQuery listened on the subs, how could it know about subs that are created later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these events:

```
$(".top").bind("mouseover mouseout", function(e) {
});

$(".top").on("mouseover mouseout", ".sub", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

are attached to `.top`. But the second one is a delegated event and jQuery emulates it like it is a normal event. If you remove `stopPropagation`:

```
$(".top").bind("mouseover mouseout", function(e) {
});

$(".top").on("mouseover mouseout", ".sub", function(e) {
});
```

you will notice that the second event is fired first as if it was attached directly to `.sub`. jQuery emulates the propagation for delegated events as if it is a normal event.

So obviously if a child element stops propagation the parent element will not receive the event. But as i mentioned it is just an emulation in jQuery.

**UPDATE**

Even though jQuery official site explains it pretty well on http://api.jquery.com/on/, i will try to explain `on` method briefly.

`on` method was introduced in jQuery 1.7. It is considered as a replacement for a couple of methods that were used before for binding events: `bind`, `delegate` and `live`. The last 2 of them were used for attaching delegated events. Now you can attach them with a single method `on`.

*Regular event*:

```
$(".top").on("mouseover mouseout", function(e) {

});
```

is completely the same as

```
$(".top").bind("mouseover mouseout", function(e) {

});
```

*Delegated event*:

```
$(".top").on("mouseover mouseout", ".sub", function(e) {

});
```

is the same as

```
$(".top").delegate(".sub", "mouseover mouseout", function(e) {

});
```

**What are delegated events used for?**

- if your html is dynamically changed on the fly. E.g. you have a `<table>` and you bind some events on table rows:

  ```
  $("table tr").on("click", function(e) {

  });
  ```

  This event with not fire on dynamicaly inserted rows. A workaround can be using delegated events:

  ```
  $("table").on("click", "tr", function(e) {

  });
  ```

  The event is attached to the table not the rows. So it can handle any row that is inserted later.
- if you have a massive bunch of similar elements. In this case if you bind events directly on the elements it may slow down your app. At least in IE:) So using delegated events may significantly increase the performance. You can look at the example from the 1st point.

**How does delegated events work?**

Let's take the example with `<table>`:

```
    $("table").on("click", "tr", function(e) {

    });
```

we attach the event on the table but ask it to check if the event was initiated on `tr`.

The rough implementation of the example above could look like this:

```
    $("table").on("click", function(e) {
        var tr = $(e.target).parentsUntil(this, 'tr');
        if (tr.length){
            //the event was triggered on tr inside table
            //do some stuff
        }
    });
```

Comment: Then what about this test http://jsfiddle.net/mgs_jsfiddle/sdNes/, where another layer is placed in between top and sub? If the mouse is moved into the gray area, is it ok that the mid-handler is called? It would be consistent if either both ancestors or none would be called?

Comment: You are right it would be consistent. But as i said jQuery just emulates it. And it cannot fire delegated event before direct event. First direct event is fired then the event bubbles up the DOM and is catched in `.top`. And then jQuery tries to find `.sub` element and perform your callback on it.

Comment: So it is important to understand that coding an "on" for an ancestor is not the same as coding a "bind" for each of the elements that satisfy the selector.

Comment: Actually `bind` is obsolete. You should use `on` in both cases. The only difference is in the 2nd parameter. If it is a selector string then jQuery treats it as a delegated event.

Comment: Obsolete? After having understood today's fiddles I think that `on` is somewhat strange regarding stopPropagation. There are reasons to use `bind` when needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the additional explanation. Previously I thought that "delegating the `sub` events to `top` is the same as binding directly to all individual `sub`". I understood that this is not correct.